# Python module semantics vs. Ruby module semantics in their C-APIs

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

I've been using Python for a long time and I've just started to toy around with Ruby, but I'm finding the differences between modules in the two languages really confusing, especially when viewed through their C-APIs. For example, here is a small ruby C module

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "ruby.h"

VALUE PyModule = Qnil;
void Init_pymodule();
VALUE method_Py_Initialize();
VALUE method_PyRun_SimpleString();

void Init_pymodule() {
    PyModule = rb_define_module("PyModule");
    rb_define_method(PyModule, "Py_Initialize", method_Py_Initialize, 0);
    rb_define_method(PyModule, "PyRun_SimpleString", method_PyRun_SimpleString, 1);
}

VALUE method_Py_Initialize(VALUE self) {
    Py_Initialize();
    return Qnil;
}

VALUE method_PyRun_SimpleString(VALUE self, VALUE command) {
    return INT2NUM(PyRun_SimpleString(RSTRING(command)->as.ary));
}
```

When I import and call that like so

```
require "pymodule"
PyModule.Py_Initialize()
PyModule.PyRun_SimpleString("print 'hellooo'")
```

I expected it to work similar to how python's modules would work. However, I am finding that I have to either use `PyModule` to extend a class or I must use `include "PyModule"`. I'm looking for a way to have `PyModule` attach these functions to the module object similar to Python's semantics. I'm also curious what is actually happening in Ruby that gives it this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module can be useful as namespaces, in both Ruby and Python, but modules in Ruby are different in that they serve as mixins too.

Your confusion is between *instance* methods (like those that you are defining and that are imported when including a Module) and *singleton* methods (like those that you are trying to call and that are not imported on inclusion).

You can use `rb_define_singleton_method` instead of `rb_define_method` and you will get the effect you want. In that case, though, your module will not have any instance methods, so including it or extending it won't have any effect.

I personally prefer to define the methods as instance methods and extend the module *with itself* so the methods are available in both ways. In C, you can use `rb_extend_object(PyModule, PyModule);` to do that.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue. Ruby has an interesting metaclass model given that you can extend a class with itself.